# var Typescript to scss

Tags: ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 app that reads a value from a database table.

I want to send this value to the scss file of the page as a parameter, since I have an animation that depends on it.

I will be grateful if you can tell me if this is possible, and if so, how. I send the code, thank you very much!

In this example, I want to replace 25 with the value of the variable this.time_rpta

Scss:

```
animation: circleRight 25s linear forwards;
```

ts:

```
this.tiempo_rpta
```

Answer (score 0):

you can done like this

HTML CODE

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'animation':  tiempo_rpta + 's'  + ' linear forwards'}"></div>
```

ts Code

```
this.tiempo_rpta = 25;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.....how do i vote?